# Getting server error 500

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, mysqli

I am getting an error 500, and when I check the logs on GoDaddy, it am getting below error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Class 'CI_DB_mysqli_result' not found in /home/rahmanhabib1/public_html/portal/system/database/DB_driver.php on line 706

and when I go to DB_Driver.php on line 706,

```
// Load and instantiate the result driver
$driver     = $this->load_rdriver();
$RES        = new $driver($this);
```

also the DB driver settings for my database are set to mysqli, and hosting with GoDaddy. Can't seem to find the issue as when I run it on local host, everything seems to be fine.

Comment: Are you trying to query an empty table by chance? The file and line that it points to (DB_Driver.php:706) is not the cause of the problem... what's actually causing the problem is whatever code is calling upon that file and method.

Comment: no the table is full, however when i seem to fill up all the information on my form and press submit it's fine. but when some values are left empty it seems to be the cause of the problem

Answer (score 1):

Check your apache error logs,try changing your .htaccess to

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

OR

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|public|\.txt) 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually there is no any fault with **[`DB_driver.php`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33511532/getting-server-error-500#comment54809086_33511532)**.

You may using Codeigniter V2. So in Codeigniter V2 they use database driver is `MySQL`. So if you use `mysqli` it will end up with this error.

If you want change `MySQL` to `mysqli`, follow method as below

**1. In `config/database.php`**

**Change**

```
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
```

to

```
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysqli';
```

**2. In `system/database/DB_driver.php`**

**Change**

```
var $dbdriver       = 'mysql';
```

to

```
var $dbdriver       = 'mysqli';
```

Comment: It was already set to mysqli, and it didn't much of a difference when i change it to mysql. thank's for the advice

Comment: There is two place you have to change